# How to consume a document in attachment pipeline using elasticsearch ruby?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-ruby

I am trying to attach a document in elasticsearch pipeline but I didn't any method for it.

For this call -

```
PUT my_index/my_type/my_id?pipeline=attachment
{
  "data": "e1xydGYxXGFuc2kNCkxvcmVtIGlwc3VtIGRvbG9yIHNpdCBhbWV0DQpccGFyIH0="
}
```

Please let me know if you know it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
client.index index: 'my_index', type: 'my_type', id: 'my_id', pipeline: 'attachment', body: { data: 'e1...H0=' }
```